# ngSubmit not working, but onsubmit is working

Tags: angular

app.module.ts

```js
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/authconfig.interceptor';


    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
    import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
    import { TableListComponent } from './table-list/table-list.component';
    import { TypographyComponent } from './typography/typography.component';
    import { IconsComponent } from './icons/icons.component';
    import { MapsComponent } from './maps/maps.component';
    import { NotificationsComponent } from './notifications/notifications.component';
    import { UpgradeComponent } from './upgrade/upgrade.component';
    import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminLayoutComponent,

      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthInterceptor,
          multi: true
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

signup.component.html

```js
    <div class="auth-wrapper">
    <form class="form-signin"   [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser()" >
        <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center">Please sign up</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

signup.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
    import { AuthService } from './../../shared/auth.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-signup',
      templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
    })

    export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
      signupForm: FormGroup;

      constructor(
        public fb: FormBuilder,
        public authService: AuthService,
        public router: Router
      ) {
        this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
          name: [''],
          email: [''],
          mobile: [''],
          password: ['']
        })
      }

      ngOnInit() { }

      registerUser() {
        this.authService.signUp(this.signupForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
          if (res.result) {
            this.signupForm.reset()
            this.router.navigate(['log-in']);
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

If i change ngSubmit to onsubmit ="alert('hi')" it does the alert when submit, but if i put (ngSubmit)="alert('hi')", it does nothing
I've already tried to put the alert in the registerUser function, and nothing happens

EDIT: Added app.module.ts, it's all already imported there, I don't get where u guys want me to import it

Comment: Do u take any error in developer console?

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule` and/or `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module?

Comment: can you go on stackblitz and create a verifiable example of this?

Comment: yeah i got one error, but i think it isn't the problem : core.js:8046 Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need something like this in whatever module this component is in:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class YourModule { }
```

importing the ReactiveFormsModule will make the directives register correctly.

Comment: that's done, i've just checked it, and its all imported and okay

Comment: you're missing something... your code works fine.. are your sure you're importing it in the CORRECT module? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4jruc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: well.. i dont know what can it be, tell me the files i should share with you

Comment: based on the error you're seeing, you definitely have not imported the ReactiveFormsModule correctly... I'd show the module code for where ever this component is declared

Comment: i dont get where do u guys want me to import it, its already imported in app.module.ts, am i dumb?

Comment: it needs to be imported into the module where SignupComponent is declared. based on your imports, you have multiple modules. As I said, show the Module where SignupComponent is declared

Comment: bryan60, component.ts is the module

Comment: no it's not. a component is not a module. in your module code `SignupComponent` isn't in the declarations array, so it needs to be somewhere else. show the module where SIGNUPCOMPONENT is DECLARED

Comment: i'm a bit new on this, i can't get what file u want XDD, what do u mean declared, SignUpComponent is there, on components.module.ts there are only components declared, not things like reactiveform, and that's the last file where it's typed "SignUpcomponent", the others are already in the post

Comment: as i've been saying.... the `ReactiveFormsModule` needs to be imported to the module where `SignUpComponent` is DECLARED!!! which means you must import `ReactiveFormsModule` to `ComponentsModule`... to use reactive forms, you must import it to the module where the components are actually using it. importing it to root doesn't make it available to sub modules.

Comment: thanks for ur patience bryan60, done, and working, sorry for my dumbness